# Swift: obtain module at runtime?

Tags: swift, reflection, module, runtime

In Swift, at runtime, is it possible to know the name of the module code is running in?

I'd want something like (and this is totally imaginary code)

```
let moduleName: String = CompileTimeInfo.moduleName
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69317959/45813).

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: It would help with runtime verification of build settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riffing off of @CouchDeveloper's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69318977/45813), you can get the module name for an arbitrary Swift *type*. You can use this to get the module name of any arbitrary code, by creating a type for this purpose.

```
func moduleName(for type: Any.Type) -> String {
  // parse module name from string that looks like "ModuleName.ClassName"
  if let subSequence = String(reflecting: type.self).split(separator: ".").first {
    return String(subSequence)
  } else {
    return ""
  }
}

print(moduleName(for: String.self)) // -> Swift

enum Test {}
print(moduleName(for: Test.self))   // -> SwiftModuleNameExample
```

This can even be embedded into a protocol.

```
public protocol Module {}
extension Module {
  static var name: String { moduleName(for: Self.self) }
}

class ThisModule: Module {}

print(ThisModule.name)             // -> SwiftModuleNameExample
```

A macOS command-line Xcode project for this code lives [here](https://github.com/claybridges/SwiftModuleNameExample).

Answer (score 1):

You might take advantage of the fact that the module name is used as a namespace and `debugPrint` ing a type will be prefixed with the module name:

```
enum Test {}
var string: String = ""
debugPrint(Test.self, to: &string)     
print("Module name: \(string.split(separator: ".").first ?? "")")
```

Note: the type must be defined in the actual module. So, wrap first three lines into a function and return the module name, done.

Comment: This is a nicely creative hack, _kudos_ and _thanks!_